# mySql not working after upgrading to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, mysql, ruby

After upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04 when i start rails server it gives this error:

```
arslion@arslion-Lenovo-B570e:~$ rails s 
/home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.43 but the client library is 5.6.24. (RuntimeError)
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/arslion/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arslion/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/arslion/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/arslion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arslion/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /home/arslion/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the gem often solves the problem .That solution worked for me .

1. `gem uninstall mysql2` and then
2. `bundle install`

Hope that works .